# React Suite (rsuitejs) CSS conflicts

Tags: css, reactjs, suite, rsuite

(Beginner here) I have a react project created with create-react-app, in a module I am importing rsuite (v5) components and styles as following:

```
import 'rsuite/dist/rsuite.min.css';
import { DateRangePicker, InputPicker } from 'rsuite';
```

but rsuite overrides my css globally.

I tried to import styles individually

```
import 'rsuite/DateRangePicker/styles/index.less';
import 'rsuite/InputPicker/styles/index.less';
```

but nothing happens.

How can I prevent rsuite from overriding my css ?

Comment: I tried using modularised imports with React Suite v4 but no styles are being applied:

`import 'rsuite/lib/DateRangePicker/styles';
import 'rsuite/lib/InputPicker/styles';
import DateRangePicker from 'rsuite/lib/DateRangePicker';
import InputPicker from 'rsuite/lib/InputPicker';`

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to solve this issue in rsuite v5

```
import "rsuite/dist/rsuite-no-reset.min.css";
```

instead of

```
import 'rsuite/dist/rsuite.min.css';
```